# How to call a Object.keys as a variable not a text in array.push?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, ejs

Help my problem is when the program runs, the values on Object.keys is on text, and i want it on variable form so it will call it on the EJS.

the output of the console.log(arr) will be (see code below):

```
[
    'req.body.name',
    'req.body.age',
    'req.body.sex',
    '2017-05-02 08:43:13',
    '031418003000',
    '1222',
    '1234',
    '01'
]
```

The first arr.push (the one with Object.keys foreach loop) is the first three elements is called as text, and i want it on variable or look like the second arr.push.

The second arr.push(the one with dateString variable to the last push) is correct because it called from the EJS.

```
var arr = [];
var m = new Date();

var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

var dateString =
m.getFullYear() + "-" +
("0" + (m.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
("0" + m.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " +
("0" + m.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
("0" + m.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
("0" + m.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key) {
  arr.push('req.body.' + key);
});
arr.push(dateString, req.body.eacode, req.body.hcn, req.body.shsn, req.body.MEMBER_CODE );

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `arr.push(req.body[key]);`

Comment: thanks @4castle !!!! it worked